# How allow passing just "allowed" delegates as parameter of function in C#

Tags: c#, parameters, delegates

I have a bit interresting problem, i wasn't able to find solution. I have 4 different delegates and want to use junt one of them as parameter of function. But the only solution, I found is :

```
void doSomething(Delegate delegate){ }
```

but I don't want to be able pass every delegate but just one of these:

```
public delegate void CopyStatusDelegate(long fileSize, long copied);
public delegate void CopyProgressDelegate(int progress);
public delegate void CopyEstimatedDelegate(int copyTimeSeconds, int estimatedTimeSeconds);
public delegate void CopyAllInfoDelegate(long fileSize, long copied, int progress, int copyTimeSeconds, int estimatedTimeSeconds);
```

Is in c# any else solution except of throwing an Exception when input delegate isn't one of these?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Write four overloads of `doSomething`, each of which accepts one of these delegates. The compiler will prevent you from passing in anything else, and if you need to for some reason (it's not very clear) you can forward from these overloads to a `protected` or `private` method that accepts any delegate.